# jquery latest owlcarousel plugin usage issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Whenever i am trying to use the latest jquery based plugins (with Asp.net mvc5/ core) and download the sample/example source, i find many plugins rather than just one.

for example : i downloaded below plugin for making the slider.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Now there are many folders, js files and css files.
Which one will be used and how 'll it be used.

i am feeling confused. Things are still unclear.

Can anyone guide me about it ?

It seems that these plugins are developed something from Node.js as well?

Comment: Almost all plugins have a guide, and this also looks good !! https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html

Comment: Thank u Baro. But i am seeing this change in almost every famous jquery plugin.

Comment: like Global.js and jqueryIdletimeout and store.js. have you tried that ? things are not really helpful.

Comment: There isn't universal guide for everything !! if you want implement a plugin, you must read the specific guide. With the experience you wil learn to read fast only what you need. This job (or hobby) can only be done if you have passion, it take time and patience.

Comment: yes you are right. but have you seen the downloaded source ?
it contains package.json and bower which belongs to nodejs npm pakages.

Comment: and have you tried store.js ? 
https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/
also please read about it. where is the helping material of this ?

Comment: same is the issue with this plugin as well 
https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize
something has been changed recently in plugins

Comment: No I don't know it. The guide ? scroll the page. On github.com usually the "home" of the plugin (or of the specific source code) is the guide, but sometimes in that page the author write the own link of the project. Not send to me all the links of the plugins, the only thing you must to do, is to read. :)

Comment: Using npm:

// Example store.js usage with npm
var store = require('store')
store.set('user', { name:'Marcus' })
store.get('user').name == 'Marcus'

Comment: i tried much but couldn't run it in my mvc project and there is not any clue about it even i have read this one